# MySQL Conditional insert to one table if a certain row does not exist on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

Is it possible to do an insert query like this?

```
INSERT INTO `table_1`
VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM `table_2`
  WHERE col1='somevalue'
)=0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO `table_1`(col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM (SELECT 'val1' as col1,'val2' as col2, 'val3' as col3) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM table_2 t2
                      WHERE t2.col1 = 'somevalue'
                     );
```

Notes:

- This seems really strange.  Limiting inserts into `table_1` when no row exists in `table_2` with *other* values.
- `NOT EXISTS` is more efficient than using `COUNT(*)`.
- You should always list the columns when using `INSERT`.

Comment: You may be able to use the [special `DUAL` table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table), to simplify the query construction to: `INSERT INTO table_1 (col1, col2, col3) SELECT 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 WHERE col1 = 'somevalue');`.